# Update a single plan in a multiple plan stripe subscription - WixCode

Tags: javascript, arrays, stripe-payments, velo

When working with stripe's multiple plans per subscription how to update a quantity or cancel a single plan from that multiple plan subscription because in response i get only 1 sub Id.

When it is a single plan subscription i update it like this:

```
let item = {
    "quantity": quantity,
    "prorate": "false"
};
subscription(subId, item) //backend function
```

or if i want to cancel it i do this:

```
let item = {
    "cancel_at_period_end": 'true'
};
subscription(subId, item) //backend function
```

but how to cancel Plan A in a multiple plans subscription with Plan A & Plan B?

Using Wix Code for project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each plan on a subscription with multiple plans is represented by a [subscription_item](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_items?lang=node).

You can remove a single plan by [deleting its subscription item](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_items/delete?lang=node) (if you want to prorate that plan for the current billing cycle, make sure you set `prorate` to `true`).